# HTML Links on IzPack HTMLInfoPanel not working correctly

Tags: installation, izpack

In my installer (created using IzPack) i am using HTMLInfoPanel, in the HTML data for this info panel I have a website link and an email address.

The problem is 
1) When I click on the website link, the page is opened in the Installer panel itself, instead of open the page in the default browse window.

2) When I click on the email link, the page in the panel just refreshes and does nothing instead of opening the mail client for the user.

Following is HTML for the link:

```
    <a href="http://www.XYZ.com/" target="_blank">XYZ, Ltd.</a>
```

HTML for the eMail link:

```
    <A HREF="mailto:support@XYZ.com" target="_blank">support@XYZ.com</A>
```

I couldn't find any help fixing this in the IzPack documentation other forums.
Can somebody help solve this?

I am using IzPack V 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the IzPack version that I was using. After upgrading the version this does not happen now.